# I am having problem with my code in python. It keeps displaying the wrong state information

Tags: python

I am having problem with my code in python. It keeps displaying the wrong state information. When I type in alaska or arizona, the print_info prints out information for alabama. I am making an income tax calculator for a class project. I would really appreciate the help. I had 50 states in this code, but I only included a portion of it. When ever I run the code, it does not matter which state I type in the end result looks like this:

[image].

```
state = input("Enter state: ")
status = input("Enter your filing status: ")
income = float(input("Enter your income: $"))


if state == "Alabama" or "alabama" or "AL" or "al":
    def al(al_income):
        if status == "single":
            if al_income <= 500:
                return al_income * 0.02
            elif al_income <= 3000:
                return 500 * 0.02 + (al_income - 500) * 0.04
            else:
                return 500 * 0.02 + (3000 - 500) * 0.02 + (al_income - 3000) * 0.05

        elif status == "married filed jointly" or "filed jointly":
            if al_income <= 1000:
                return al_income * 0.02
            elif al_income <= 6000:
                return 1000 * 0.02 + (al_income - 1000) * 0.04
            else:
                return 1000 * 0.02 + (6000 - 1000) * 0.04 + (al_income - 6000) * 0.05

        elif status == "married filed separately" or "filed separately":
            if al_income <= 500:
                return al_income * 0.02
            elif al_income <= 3000:
                return 500 * 0.02 + (al_income - 500) * 0.04
            else:
                return 500 * 0.02 + (3000 - 500) * 0.04 + (al_income - 3000) * 0.05

        elif status == "head of household":
            if al_income <= 500:
                return al_income * 0.02
            elif al_income <= 3000:
                return 500 * 0.02 + (al_income - 500) * 0.04
            else:
                return 500 * 0.02 + (3000 - 500) * 0.02 + (al_income - 3000) * 0.05

    def print_info(al_income, afterTaxes):
        print("Total federal taxes you pays: $", round(afterTaxes, 2))
        al_loss = al(al_income)
        ssc_tax = income * 0.062
        medi_tax = income * 0.0145
        fica = ssc_tax + medi_tax
        retirement = float(input("Enter the retirement saving amount: $"))
        final_income = income - afterTaxes - al_loss - fica
        ret_income = income - afterTaxes - al_loss - fica - retirement
        print("Total Alabama state taxes you pay: $", round(al_loss, 2))
        print("Total FICA tax deducted: $", round(fica, 2))
        print("Income after fed taxes: $", round(income - afterTaxes, 2))
        print("Income after Alabama state taxes: $", round(final_income, 2))
        print("Income after retirement saving: $", round(ret_income, 2))


    if status == "single":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85525) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) 
                          * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) 
                          * 0.35 + \ (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed jointly" or "filed jointly":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 19750:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 80250:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (income - 19750) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 171050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (income - 80250) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 326600:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 414700:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (income - 326600) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 622050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (income - 414700) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (518400 - 414700) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 622050) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed separately" or "filed separately":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 311025:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 19750) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (311025 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 311025) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "head of household":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 14100:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 53700:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (income - 14100) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85500:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (income - 53700) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85500) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")



elif state == "Alaska" or "alaska" or " AK" or "ak":
    def ak(ak_income):
        return 0

    def print_info(ak_income, afterTaxes):
        print("Total federal taxes you pays: $", round(afterTaxes, 2))
        ak_loss = ak(ak_income)
        ssc_tax = income * 0.062
        medi_tax = income * 0.0145
        fica = ssc_tax + medi_tax
        retirement = float(input("Enter the retirement saving amount: $"))
        final_income = income - afterTaxes - ak_loss - fica
        ret_income = income - afterTaxes - ak_loss - fica - retirement
        print("Total Alaska state taxes you pay: $", round(ak_loss, 2))
        print("Total FICA tax deducted: $", round(fica, 2))
        print("Income after fed taxes: $", round(income - afterTaxes, 2))
        print("Income after Alaska state taxes: $", round(final_income, 2))
        print("Income after retirement saving: $", round(ret_income, 2))


    if status == "single":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85525) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed jointly" or "filed jointly":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 19750:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 80250:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (income - 19750) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 171050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (income - 80250) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 326600:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 414700:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (income - 326600) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 622050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (income - 414700) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (518400 - 414700) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 622050) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed separately" or "filed separately":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 311025:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 19750) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (311025 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 311025) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "head of household":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 14100:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 53700:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (income - 14100) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85500:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (income - 53700) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85500) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

elif state == "Arizona" or "arizona" or "AZ" or "az":
    def az(az_income):
        if status == "single":
            if az_income <= 26500:
                return az_income * 0.0259
            elif az_income <= 53000:
                return 26500 * 0.0259 + (az_income - 26500) * 0.0334
            elif az_income <= 159000:
                return 26500 * 0.0259 + (53000 - 26500) * 0.0334 + (az_income - 53000) * 0.0417
            else:
                return 26500 * 0.0259 + (53000 - 26500) * 0.0334 + (159000 - 53000) * 0.0417 + \
                       (az_income - 3750) * 0.045

        elif status == "married filed jointly" or "filed jointly":
            if az_income <= 53000:
                return az_income * 0.0259
            elif az_income <= 106000:
                return 53000 * 0.0259 + (az_income - 53000) * 0.0334
            elif az_income <= 318000:
                return 53000 * 0.0259 + (106000 - 53000) * 0.0334 + (az_income - 106000) * 0.0417
            else:
                return 53000 * 0.0259 + (106000 - 53000) * 0.0334 +  (318000 - 106000) * 0.0417 + \
                       (az_income - 318000) * 0.0450

        elif status == "married filed separately" or "filed separately":
            if az_income <= 26500:
                return az_income * 0.0259
            elif az_income <= 53000:
                return 26500 * 0.0259 + (az_income - 26500) * 0.0334
            elif az_income <= 159000:
                return 26500 * 0.0259 + (53000 - 26500) * 0.0334 + (az_income - 53000) * 0.0417
            else:
                return 26500 * 0.0259 + (53000 - 26500) * 0.0334 + (159000 - 53000) * 0.0417 + \
                       (az_income - 3750) * 0.045

        elif status == "head of household":
            if az_income <= 53000:
                return az_income * 0.0259
            elif az_income <= 106000:
                return 53000 * 0.0259 + (az_income - 53000) * 0.0334
            elif az_income <= 318000:
                return 53000 * 0.0259 + (106000 - 53000) * 0.0334 + (az_income - 106000) * 0.0417
            else:
                return 53000 * 0.0259 + (106000 - 53000) * 0.0334 + (318000 - 106000) * 0.0417 + \
                       (az_income - 318000) * 0.0450

    def print_info(az_income, afterTaxes):
        print("Total federal taxes you pays: $", round(afterTaxes, 2))
        az_loss = az(az_income)
        ssc_tax = income * 0.062
        medi_tax = income * 0.0145
        fica = ssc_tax + medi_tax
        retirement = float(input("Enter the retirement saving amount: $"))
        final_income = income - afterTaxes - az_loss - fica
        ret_income = income - afterTaxes - az_loss - fica - retirement
        print("Total Arizona state taxes you pay: $", round(az_loss, 2))
        print("Total FICA tax deducted: $", round(fica, 2))
        print("Income after fed taxes: $", round(income - afterTaxes, 2))
        print("Income after Arizona state taxes: $", round(final_income, 2))
        print("Income after retirement saving: $", round(ret_income, 2))


    if status == "single":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85525) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed jointly" or "filed jointly":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 19750:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 80250:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (income - 19750) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 171050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (income - 80250) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 326600:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 414700:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (income - 326600) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 622050:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (income - 414700) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 19750 * 0.10 + (80250 - 19750) * 0.12 + (171050 - 80250) * 0.22 + \
                         (326600 - 171050) * 0.24 + (414700 - 326600) * 0.32 + (518400 - 414700) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 622050) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "married filed separately" or "filed separately":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 9875:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 40125:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (income - 9875) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85525:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 171050) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 311025:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 9875) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 9875 * 0.10 + (40125 - 19750) * 0.12 + (85525 - 40125) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85525) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (311025 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 311025) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")

    elif status == "head of household":

        if str(int(income)) == "0":
           sys.exit()
        elif income <= 14100:
            afterTaxes = income * 0.10
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 53700:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (income - 14100) * 0.12
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 85500:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (income - 53700) * 0.22
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 163300:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (income - 85500) * 0.24
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 207350:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (income - 163300) * 0.32
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        elif income <= 518400:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (income - 207350) * 0.35
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)
        else:
            afterTaxes = 14100 * 0.10 + (53700 - 14100) * 0.12 + (85500 - 53700) * 0.22 + \
                         (163300 - 85500) * 0.24 + (207350 - 163300) * 0.32 + (518400 - 207350) * 0.35 + \
                         (income - 518400) * 0.37
            print_info(income,afterTaxes)

        print("")
```

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow. Some code is outside the area.

Comment: `or` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: should i delete the or?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if state == "Alabama" or "alabama" or "AL" or "al":
```

All those `or` clauses are taking the following strings as full expressions, not adding them to the equals check.  Let's throw in some parentheses to see how Python is interpreting it:

```
if (state == "Alabama") or ("alabama") or ("AL") or ("al"):
```

Any non-empty string is considered True, so you're always falling into the first `if` condition.

Comment: A (possible) correct solution would be `if state.lower() in ['alabama', 'al']:`

Comment: Thank you soo much, I appreciate the help.